# Implement Equatable for custom private class - Swift

Tags: swift, equatable

I know how to implement Equatable for a non-private class (by writing the == operator function), however this doesn't work for a private class given that "Operators are only allowed at global scope". Problem is, at global scope, private class is not visible, so how can I implement its == operator..?

```
private class Foo : Equatable{
    var bar = ""
}

func == (lhs: Foo, rhs: Foo) -> Bool {
        return lhs.bar == rhs.bar
}
```

error: Use of undeclared type Foo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to also declare your `==` operator function as `private` for this to work. Functions are by default scoped as `internal`, and you can't have an internal method with privately scoped parameters or return type.

```
private class Foo : Equatable {
    var bar = ""
}

private func ==(lhs: Foo, rhs: Foo) -> Bool {
        return lhs.bar == rhs.bar
}
```